# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query') get current tab url for v3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm referencing the instruction on https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#get-the-current-tab.

I know there are many questions on this but I want to get the url of the current tab.  The problem is I'm getting an error I'm struggling to understand.

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')`

I've tried moving the snippet of code to the background.js, pop.js, and the content.js files.

background.js

```js
async function getTabUrl() {
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true });
    console.log(tab);
    return tab[0].url;
}

getTabUrl().then(tab => console.log(tab))
```

manifest.json

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "version": "1",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "icons/favicon.ico"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "scripts/content.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                ...
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

scripts/content.js is blank.

Comment: I get a different error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')". The error occurs in the line `return tab[0].url;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')

This error says that the parent of `query` is undefined i.e. `chrome.tabs` is undefined. It happens if you run this code in the wrong place e.g. in a content script or in a web page console.

Note that chrome://extensions will show old errors even after reloading the extension, so you can clear them by clicking the trashcan icon or the `Clear all` button.

> I've tried moving the snippet of code to the background.js, pop.js, and the content.js files.

Each part of the extension has its own method of getting the active URL:

- In the content script it's just `location.href`, no need for any permissions.
- In the popup it's your getTabUrl, however since the popup is a separate window it has its own devtools and console: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu to see it.
- In the background script you would normally use the `tabId` or `tab` property of the event in your `chrome` API listener like `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`. Note that just calling getTabUrl() in the background script is pretty meaningless: it runs at browser startup, possibly before any tabs are created, or when you reload the extension so the active tab is chrome://extensions.

Note that `activeTab` is not about granting the permission to any active tab, but only to the active tab in which the user interacted with your extension explicitly, e.g. clicked the extension icon.

Answer (score 1):

This sample gets the URL of the active tab in popup.

[image]

popup.js

```js
const elmUrl = document.getElementById("url");

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
  const url = tabs[0].url;
  console.log("url=", url);
  elmUrl.innerText = url;
});
```

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "Get URL of Active tab in popup",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      font-size: x-large;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="min-width:300px;min-height:100px;">
  <span id="url"></span>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```